# Showing data in grid based off bound checked list box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

I have some code I'm taking over which deals with Languages, Categories and Phrases.

A phrase can apply to multiple languages.

The same phrase may appear in multiple categories.

Phrases and Languages appear in a Grid so the phrase can be entered with the relevant translations for the relevant languages.

When you enter a translation for one phrase it should reflect that in all the categories.

A checkbox list(which I've done) displays all categories

I'm completely new to WPF and I'm unsure how to go about setting up the ViewModel, Observeable Collections etc to handle this type of scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I believe this is the model I would need:

```
public class Phrase
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public List<Language> {get;set;}
  public List<Category> {get;set;}
}

public class Langauge
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Culture {get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Lots of questions / issues.  Suggest you break is down and start with a data model based on 3rd normal form.